# GROUP BY and sum amounts

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database table:

```
+----------+----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| animalID | foodtype | rAmount | rAmtUnits | rFrequency | rFreqUnit |
+----------+----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| 3498     | BANA     |       3 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 3455     | NUTS     |      10 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 3455     | VEGG     |      20 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 3450     | NUTS     |      10 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 3450     | VEGG     |      20 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 3450     | HAY      |     100 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 3452     | HAY      |     100 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 3452     | NUTS     |      10 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 3452     | VEGG     |      20 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 9490     | BEFR     |       2 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 2899     | BEFR     |       2 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 8393     | ANTS     |      10 | ltr.      |          1 | day       |
| 8899     | EUCL     |       5 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 4883     | FISH     |       4 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 7838     | MICE     |       3 | ea.       |          1 | wk.       |
| 7838     | RATS     |       1 | ea.       |          2 | wk.       |
| 4884     | WPLN     |       3 | lbs.      |          1 | wk.       |
| 1863     | BEFR     |       3 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 2847     | EUCL     |       3 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 4336     | BANA     |       2 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 4336     | NUTS     |       1 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 4336     | CHWM     |       2 | cups      |          1 | day       |
| 2856     | CHWM     |       2 | cups      |          1 | day       |
| 2856     | BANA     |       1 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 2856     | NUTS     |       2 | lbs.      |          1 | day       |
| 8483     | NUTS     |       2 | cups      |          1 | day       |
| 8483     | SEED     |       2 | cups      |          1 | day       |
+----------+----------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

And I want to list the amount of food and quantities needed for a week.  I have the following query:

```
SELECT foodtype,
CASE 
    WHEN rFrequency=1 AND rFreqUnit='day' THEN rAmount*7 
    WHEN rFrequency=2 AND rFreqUnit='wk.' THEN rAmount/2 
    ELSE rAmount END AS rAmount, rAmtUnits 
FROM Rations GROUP BY foodtype;
```

But with the GROUP BY, the rAmount column isn't summed up, most of the values just disappear.  I'm looking for a way so that the GROUP BY will sum up all of the values that would be there without the GROUP BY.  Any easy way to do this?

Comment: You need to aggregate the rAmount column with SUM()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to wrap your expression that returns rAmount in a SUM aggregate.

It looks like you wouldn't want to be adding "pounds" and "ounces" together, so it looks like you want to also "GROUP BY" rAmtUnits.

Given the data in your table, it looks like you would want to multiply by 7 whenever the rFreqUnit is day. It's not at all clear to me what you would want to divide by 2, in the case the rFrequency was set to a 2. Seems like if you need something twice a week, you need twice the rAmount. If you need `"N"` of something per week, you'd want to include `"N * rAmount"` in the total. Likewise, if you needed 3 of something per day, you'd want to include `"3 * rAmount * 7"` in the total.

I think you want something like this:

```
 SELECT r.foodtype
      , SUM(r.rAmount * r.rFrequency * IF(r.rFreqUnit='day',7,1)
        ) AS rAmount
      , r.rAmtUnits
   FROM Rations r
  GROUP BY r.foodtype, r.rAmtUnits
```

---

An ANSI-standard equivalent to expression `"IF(r.rFreqUnit='day',7,1)"` would be:

```
CASE r.rFreqUnit WHEN 'day' THEN 7 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: Ah yeah, the divide by two was a mistake. I was misreading the table as it meaning 1 rat every two weeks.  Thanks, though! Just what I needed.

Comment: Also, what's the point of doing `Rations r` and then doing `r.foodtype`? Is doing it how I did not a good way of querying?

Comment: What you have is fine. I'm just in the habit of qualifying all column references in a query, even when only one table is being referenced. In queries that reference more than one table, best practice is to qualify all column references in the query, and that's just a pattern that is so familiar, I just always do it, even when only one table is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
FROM Rations WHERE foodtype = FoodType
```

Put this in a function (e.g. javascript, php...) where you send **FoodType** as a parameter

Comment: I was actually just getting practice with queries. I'm not using any other web code for this. Thanks though!